# Resource consumption inside a Docker container

Tags: docker, containers, docker-machine, docker-container

```
CONTAINER      CPU %    MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %    NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
48c16e180af6   0.20%    91.48MiB / 31.31GiB   0.29%    3.86kB / 0B         85.3MB / 0B         33
f734efe5a249        0.00%    472KiB / 31.31GiB     0.00%    3.97kB / 0B         12.3kB / 0B         1
165a7b031093        0.00%    480KiB / 31.31GiB     0.00%    9.49kB / 0B         3.66MB / 0B         1
```

Does anyone know how to get resource consumption of a specific Docker container within its running environment?

Outside of a container, we can get it easily  by typing a command "docker stats". Besides, if I try to get resource consumption inside a container, it will get the consumption (RAM, CPU) of the physical computer which the container runs on.
Another option is using '**htop**' command, but it does not show the result exactly compared to 'docker stats' command.

Comment: Does your container runs in privileged mode?

Comment: if the container runs in privileged mode, how can I process further?

Comment: Since you mentioned that you are running a container within a container, that can be achieved by the docker privileged mode ryt?

Comment: Nope, I just execute one container and want to get its consumption without using "docker stats" which means outside of the container.

Comment: That means you should get the stats of docker component residing within your host machine, not the container?

Comment: yes, just one specific running container. Not all of the running on the physical computer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the processes consumption inside the container, you can go into the container and monitor the processes.

```
docker exec -it <container-name> watch ps -aux
```

Notice that after running the above command, the container doesn't know about any docker processes running.

Comment: The container is considered as a computer. Thus, I need to monitor its performance as well as resource consumption inside it. For example, after running "docker run -it <image-name>", or "docker exec -it <container-name>", it will show as "root@48c16e180af6:/root#", all actions must be executed inside the running container. Your suggestion do monitor the docker container information, is outside of the container, though, it monitors the processes running inside the container

Comment: @JohnPekl You could execute "ps -aux" inside the container to view same result.